# deadlock scenario for locking update with sorted list

Tags: sql, mysql, deadlock, database-deadlocks

assume a tableX having following schema

```
id,colA,colB,colC,colD
composite index -> colA,colB,colC
```

there is list of object and each object has field ColB and ColC, the list is then sorted

```
list = list.sortBasedOnColBThenColC();
```

a query is created based on the sorted list

```
String query = "select * from tableX where colA=request.getColA()";
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    query.append("(colB=list[i].getColB()");
    query.append("and")
    query.append("(colC=list[i].getColC())")
    query.append("or")
}
query += "for update"; // blocking read
```

now i, am executing the following transaction.

```
start transaction

execute(query)

for i in list
   int rowsUpdated = update tableX set colD+=1 where colA=request.getColA() and colB=list[i].getColB() and colC=list[i].getColC();
   if(rowsUpdated < 1){
      insert into tableX (colA,colB,colC)

commit
```

the above transaction is a part of an API, so it could be executed in parallel, but, since the list is sorted, is it possible that we may face a deadlock in this scenario?
if yes, how can we prevent it in this scenario?

Comment: Nope, a single statement cannot generate a deadlock, only a lock wait timeout issue if locked rows are not released quickly

Comment: Please provide the rest of the transaction.  The `FOR UPDATE` lasts until `COMMIT`.

Comment: @Shadow the someSortedList can have different elements, but the list would always be sorted.

Comment: @RajatAggarwal I'm sorry, but I do not understand hiw your comment is relevant to my comment.

Comment: added complete details.